# ffmpeg `-movflags use_metadata_tags` won't copy album cover metadata

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, metadata

I want to edit a mp3 file using ffmpeg while keeping the metadata. I've searched how to keep the metadata and found this [link](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/23741/how-to-prevent-ffmpeg-from-dropping-metadata). It is said to use `-movflags use_metadata_tags`.

```bash
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -movflags use_metadata_tags -af "volume=0:enable='between(t,0,0.2)'" out.mp3
```

It copies every metadata except album cover.

I found another [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1450438/ffmpeg-drops-the-album-art). It is said to use `-c:v copy` for album cover. I tried:

```bash
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -movflags use_metadata_tags -c:v copy -af "volume=0:enable='between(t,0,0.2)'" out.mp3
```

But it didn't work.

I even tried this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/996223/using-ffmpeg-to-copy-metadata-from-one-file-to-another). It is about how to copy metadata from one file to another. and it didn't work too.

How should I keep the album cover?