# Error executing script conversion image to metadata block picture

Tags: linux, script, cygwin

My system is Windows and I installed Cygwin so I can run shell and bash files. I'm having problems running the second script posted here [https://superuser.com/questions/169151](https://superuser.com/questions/169151/embed-album-art-in-ogg-through-command-line-in-linux) by @Biapy and would like some infomation:

It doesn't tell you anything about what the script's command line should look like, so I ran it by deduction!

At the beginning of script, doesn't have any interpreter definition, or is this not mandatory?!
I tested both with `#!/bin/bash` and with `#!/bin/sh`, but I have the same problems:

Note: The script is in the same directory as the input files that it will read.

Running the script without putting the full path of the input files because they are in the same directory as the script:

`sh script.sh "audio.ogg" "Cover.jpeg"`

Output script:

```
script.sh: line 7: local: can only be used in a function
script.sh: line 8: : No such file or directory
sed: can't read : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 18: local: can only be used in a function
script.sh: line 19: local: can only be used in a function
script.sh: line 22: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 25: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 29: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 32: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 35: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 38: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 40: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 43: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 46: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 49: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 54: : No such file or directory
wc: /path/to/my-cover-art.jpg: No such file or directory
script.sh: line 57: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 59: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 59: : No such file or directory
Error opening input file '/path/to/my-ogg-file.ogg'.
rm: cannot remove '': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '': No such file or directory
```

Running the script with putting the full path of the input files:

`sh script.sh "C:/Users/CMG/Desktop/audio.ogg" "C:/Users/CMG/Desktop/Cover.jpeg"`

Output script:

```
script.sh: line 7: local: can only be used in a function
script.sh: line 8: : No such file or directory
sed: can't read : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 18: local: can only be used in a function
script.sh: line 19: local: can only be used in a function
script.sh: line 22: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 25: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 29: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 32: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 35: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 38: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 40: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 43: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 46: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 49: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 54: : No such file or directory
wc: /path/to/my-cover-art.jpg: No such file or directory
script.sh: line 57: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 59: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 59: : No such file or directory
Error opening input file '/path/to/my-ogg-file.ogg'.
rm: cannot remove '': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '': No such file or directory
```

In both tests the same problems:

```
local: can only be used in a function
No such file or directory
```

Another problem is:

When the audio name has an exclamation mark, the script cancels before it even starts, see below:

Running script with audio name with exclamation mark:

`sh script.sh "audio!.ogg" "Cover.jpeg"`

Output script:

`-bash: !.ogg: event not found`

But if I run the script by putting single quotes in the input files, the -bash error goes away and it goes back to the initial error.

Running script with audio name with exclamation mark, putting single quotes in the input files:

`sh script.sh 'audio!.ogg' 'Cover.jpeg'`

Output script:

```
script.sh: line 7: local: can only be used in a function
script.sh: line 8: : No such file or directory
sed: can't read : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 18: local: can only be used in a function
script.sh: line 19: local: can only be used in a function
script.sh: line 22: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 25: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 29: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 32: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 35: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 38: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 40: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 43: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 46: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 49: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 54: : No such file or directory
wc: /path/to/my-cover-art.jpg: No such file or directory
script.sh: line 57: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 59: : No such file or directory
script.sh: line 59: : No such file or directory
Error opening input file '/path/to/my-ogg-file.ogg'.
rm: cannot remove '': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '': No such file or directory
```

Could @Biapy help?

Note:

I already run other scripts on my system with no problem.

Comment: If you start the script with `sh` it will be ran with `sh` regardless of the specified shell in the shebang. Run the script with `./scriptname` instead after making it executable.

Comment: `command` is NOT a bash/sh reserved word nor a Cygwin program. As such it will produces `No such file or directory`